# Ошибка при создании ссылки на persistentContainer

Tags: ios, swift, coredata

Настроил сущность Core Data и сгенерировал подклассы NSManagedObject.
При создании ссылки на persistentContainer появляется ошибка Force Cast Violation: Force casts should be avoided. (force_cast). Как ее исправить?

```
let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext
```

В аналогичным проекте этот же код выполнялся без ошибок.

Comment: Ругается на as! (force cast). SwiftLint на проекте? Скорее всего в нем настроено строгое правило на каст.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev да, подключен SwiftLint, спасибо